# Could VantaBlack be used as radiation proofing?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I've just been reading [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/395701/hypothetically-if-there-was-a-substance-that-could-absorb-all-visible-light-and) about the possibility of a material which reflects no visible light. A lot of the answers immediately talk about a wider spectrum, not just visible light. The answers seem to focus on a substance named VantaBlack, which prevents 99.65% of radiation from being reflected.

What happens to this radiation? Could this unusual property be used to protect a space (say, a black box recorder or bomb shelter) from radiation?

Comment: why would you want radiation shielding for a black box?

Comment: @Cursed Because recording equipment and electronic storage are often sensitive to radiation.

Comment: black boxes are designed to survive aeroplane crashes, you know that right?

Comment: @Cursed You could have a similar device on a submarine.. Although a little bit of googling suggests that it's not common practise. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: More on [vantablack](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+vantablack).

Comment: @Cursed. You can drop a credit card to the floor but better not to expose it to a magnetic field, for what it matters.

Comment: Shielding is in your name :))

Comment: Maybe a mirrored surface would work better. With VB your box is going to heat up a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Vantablack gets its name from being Vertically Aligned NanoTube Array black. It has [very low reflectance in IR and visible light](https://www.surreynanosystems.com/vantablack/science-of-vantablack). A photon that comes into the forest of nanotubes bounces around, exciting local electrons a bit and losing energy, and has a low probablity of bouncing back at the right angle to get out of the forest again. The energy gets turned into heat.

This shows one problem with protecting objects with this: they heat up from the absorbed radiation. Might not be a problem for lower intensities, but a nuclear flash will be 99.65% absorbed by the black, which presumably would ignite more easily than white or reflective surfaces that bounce off the photons.

However, the real issue is whether other radiation is stopped. The principle works for nearly anything, but different materials will interact with different radiation differently. Gamma ray photons can mess up graphite and nanotube structures, although [at least in some experiments](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6177704/) nanotube forests do fine. [Same with proton radiation](http://old.esaconferencebureau.com/custom/icso/2012/presentations/103_Kuhnhenn.pdf). But that does not mean they stop the radiation. [At least for graphite](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/XrayMassCoef/ElemTab/z06.html) the gamma stopping power decreases as the energy goes up. For protons in light elements each bounce loses some velocity and eventually they stop, but this might take a while - in theory a really thick coating might do it, but why not just have a lot of water or graphite?

I think this approach works great if you want to absorb photons at longer wavelengths. As you move towards x-rays and gammas you want more and more electrons, so you may want to have a forest of heavier atoms. Particles tend to penetrate even deeper. However, it is likely easier to just have lead shielding unless mass is at a premium (in space?) and there is less risk that you cannot see the literally black box.

Comment: In other words, Vantablack has no radiations  (em or corpuscolar) shielding properties peculiar to it (except for the ir vis radiations.